# Apache mod_rewrite Unavailable

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, debian

I have problems with apache mod_rewrite. In my vps (var/www/script/) directory **script** folder, I have a cms and want to install it. Unfortunately it says **Apache mod_rewrite Unavailable**. I have tried several solutions to resolve this problem:

- Tried `enable mod_rewrite module`:

  - `updatedb`
  - `locate mod_rewrite.so`
    (got /usr/lib/apache2/modules)
  - `cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled`
  - `touch rewrite.load`
  - used editor to paste this line `LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.s`
  - edited `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`: I have changed `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride all`
  - `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

This didn't help

- Tried type `a2enmod rewrite`. Got output :

`Module rewrite already enabled`

- Restarted couple times apache service

Im using debian.

My apache2.conf: http://pastebin.com/9m8H4SKC

Question: What I'm doing wrong and what should I do in order to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your custom rewrite.load file, run "a2enmod rewrite" again and restart Apache. Anyway, mod_rewrite is generally not needed for CMS, it's just nice to have for SEO and such.